# how to stop android app to freez?

Tags: android, multithreading, video, webrtc, glsurfaceview

I have develop video calling app using webrtc.

When new stream fetch then app goes on anr and give error like this :-

**"Thread[2,tid=18866,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb81f4498,peer=0x12d260a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3"**

we have create render using GLSurfaceView. we have create four remote rendor into one GLSurfaceView.

First time all four render display video but when some one rejoin into same room then android app get error and app goes on freeze mode.

how can load more video stream without anr dialog.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having any intensive operation, like decoding video Streaming , use a separate thread if you haven't yet, but not the operations which are communicating with UI elements . See if that helps